# Should I use the same name for a class when extending it with a namespace in PHP?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, extends

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Person
{
  public function doSeomthing()
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I want to extend this class to add extra functionality, using my own namespace. Is it a good or bad idea to use the same class name? For example:

namespace Custom;

```
class Person extends \Person
{
  public function doSomethingElse()
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I'm particularly interested as to what PSR standards might feel about this.

Comment: As long as it is your namespace i think you should name it as it makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same class names, or `Name collisions` is one of the problems that namespaces are specifically designed to solve.. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

```
In the PHP world, namespaces are designed to solve two problems that authors 
of libraries and applications encounter when creating re-usable code elements 
such as classes or functions:

1.Name collisions between code you create, and internal PHP 
classes/functions/constants or third-party classes/functions/constants.

2. Ability to alias (or shorten) Extra_Long_Names designed to alleviate 
the first problem, improving readability of source code.
```